# URL rewriting for CTP assigned entity

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, url-rewriting

I have a multisite install where base permalink structure is following:

```
domain.tld/<site_slug>/news/%postname%/
```

thats the way defaults posts are created.

Now there is a CPT ***Office***, that registers slug *office* like this

```
'rewrite' => [
  'slug' => 'office',
  'with_front' => false,
]
```

this way I can have links for offices as

```
domain.tld/<site_slug>/office/%office%/
```

Now i need to create 'pages' assigned to these offices. For now i am creating another CPT ***office-page***, but i dont know how to assign it to office.

I need following structure

```
domain.tld/<site_slug>/office/%officename%/pages/%pagename%/
```

how can i achieve that? Do I must create another CPT or it will be working with default pages in wordpress?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Why wouldn't you just make the post type hierarchical and have a structure like `domain.tld/<site_slug>/office/%officename%/%pagename%/`? Would be much simpler to set up and maintain. Otherwise, you could look as using something like post meta to link pages to an office, or use something like [Posts2Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) to link pages or posts to an office, and then use rewrite rules to set it up the way you want